# Multiply numeric columns of two different dataframes based on matching of other columns

Tags: r

I have the first dataframe like:

```
df1<-structure(list(`Demand Per Section` = c(80, 125, 350, 100, 538, 
75, 25, 138, 138, 75, 150, 37, 225, 35, 40, 125, 25, 25, 125, 
50), `Element Name` = c("Naphthalene", "Nitric acid (concentrated)", 
"Sulphuric acid(concentrated)", "2-hydroxybenzoic acid", "Acetic anhydride", 
"2-Naphthol", "Sodium Hydroxide", "Phenyl hydrazine hydrochloride", 
"Glucose", "Sodium acetate", "Aniline", "Zinc poweder", "2-amino-benzoic acid", 
"1.3-dihydroxybenzene", "Ethyl acetate", "hydroxy benzene", "phenyl methanol", 
"Sodium carbonate", "Potassium permanganate", "Sodium bisulfite."
), `Course Name` = c("Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", 
"Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", 
"Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", 
"Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1"), Department = c("Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`81` = 81L, 
`101` = 101L, `127` = 127L, `134` = 134L, `135` = 135L, `136` = 136L, 
`174` = 174L, `183` = 183L, `220` = 220L, `225` = 225L, `245` = 245L, 
`286` = 286L, `288` = 288L, `290` = 290L, `305` = 305L, `314` = 314L, 
`324` = 324L, `329` = 329L), class = "omit"))

`Demand Per Section` `Element Name`                 `Course Name` Department
                  <dbl> <chr>                          <chr>         <chr>     
 1                   80 Naphthalene                    Course 1      Chemsitry 
 2                  125 Nitric acid (concentrated)     Course 1      Chemsitry 
 3                  350 Sulphuric acid(concentrated)   Course 1      Chemsitry 
 4                  100 2-hydroxybenzoic acid          Course 1      Chemsitry 
 5                  538 Acetic anhydride               Course 1      Chemsitry 
 6                   75 2-Naphthol                     Course 1      Chemsitry 
 7                   25 Sodium Hydroxide               Course 1      Chemsitry 
 8                  138 Phenyl hydrazine hydrochloride Course 1      Chemsitry 
 9                  138 Glucose                        Course 1      Chemsitry 
10                   75 Sodium acetate                 Course 1      Chemsitry 
11                  150 Aniline                        Course 1      Chemsitry 
12                   37 Zinc poweder                   Course 1      Chemsitry 
13                  225 2-amino-benzoic acid           Course 1      Chemsitry 
14                   35 1.3-dihydroxybenzene           Course 1      Chemsitry 
15                   40 Ethyl acetate                  Course 1      Chemsitry 
16                  125 hydroxy benzene                Course 1      Chemsitry 
17                   25 phenyl methanol                Course 1      Chemsitry 
18                   25 Sodium carbonate               Course 1      Chemsitry
```

and a second dataframe like:

```
df2<-structure(list(`Course name` = c("Course 1", "Course 2", "Course 3", 
"Course 4", "Course 1", "Course 2", "Course 3", "Course 4", "Course 5", 
"Course 1", "Course 2", "Course 3", "Course 4", "Course 5"), 
    `number of sections` = c(3, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 7, 10, 3, 4, 5, 
    6, 2, 2), Department = c("Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Biology", "Biology", "Biology", "Biology", 
    "Biology", "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", "Physics"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))


`Course name` `number of sections` Department
   <chr>                        <dbl> <chr>     
 1 Course 1                         3 Chemsitry 
 2 Course 2                         5 Chemsitry 
 3 Course 3                         3 Chemsitry 
 4 Course 4                         4 Chemsitry 
 5 Course 1                         7 Biology   
 6 Course 2                         2 Biology   
 7 Course 3                         7 Biology   
 8 Course 4                        10 Biology   
 9 Course 5                         3 Biology   
10 Course 1                         4 Physics   
11 Course 2                         5 Physics   
12 Course 3                         6 Physics   
13 Course 4                         2 Physics   
14 Course 5                         2 Physics
```

What I want is to create a new column in `df1` named `DemandCourse` which will look into `df2` in the columns of `Course Name` and `Department` and when both will match with `Course Name` and `Department` of `df1` it will multiply the `Demand per Section` of `df1` with the `number of sections` of `df2`. So for example the first row of the new column will be 80*3 =240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to join (`left_join`) and then `mutate` to create the column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- left_join(df1, df2,
     by = c("Course Name" = "Course name", "Department")) %>% 
   mutate(DemandCourse = `Demand Per Section` * `number of sections`,
    .keep = "unused")
```

-output

```
> df1
# A tibble: 20 × 4
   `Element Name`                 `Course Name` Department DemandCourse
   <chr>                          <chr>         <chr>             <dbl>
 1 Naphthalene                    Course 1      Chemsitry           240
 2 Nitric acid (concentrated)     Course 1      Chemsitry           375
 3 Sulphuric acid(concentrated)   Course 1      Chemsitry          1050
 4 2-hydroxybenzoic acid          Course 1      Chemsitry           300
 5 Acetic anhydride               Course 1      Chemsitry          1614
 6 2-Naphthol                     Course 1      Chemsitry           225
 7 Sodium Hydroxide               Course 1      Chemsitry            75
 8 Phenyl hydrazine hydrochloride Course 1      Chemsitry           414
 9 Glucose                        Course 1      Chemsitry           414
10 Sodium acetate                 Course 1      Chemsitry           225
11 Aniline                        Course 1      Chemsitry           450
12 Zinc poweder                   Course 1      Chemsitry           111
13 2-amino-benzoic acid           Course 1      Chemsitry           675
14 1.3-dihydroxybenzene           Course 1      Chemsitry           105
15 Ethyl acetate                  Course 1      Chemsitry           120
16 hydroxy benzene                Course 1      Chemsitry           375
17 phenyl methanol                Course 1      Chemsitry            75
18 Sodium carbonate               Course 1      Chemsitry            75
19 Potassium permanganate         Course 1      Chemsitry           375
20 Sodium bisulfite.              Course 1      Chemsitry           150
```